# image orientation in ELCImagepicker

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, elcimagepickercontroller

I am using ELCImagePicker in my project. After selecting images using ELCImagePicker I am showing it on an ImageView.
The portrait images are working fine but the landscape images are getting rotated in my UIImageview. Why it is happening ?
Please advice. Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{



 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];
 for(NSDictionary *dict in info) {

    UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     [images addObject:image];
     UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
 [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
}

   }
```